# Why MATCHES WITH condition doesn't match twice

Tags: regex, perl

I have a script which parse some cell related data in the file.

Here is the script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    print "Hi - $line" if ($line =~ /^END$/);
}

__DATA__
MANAGED DATA
SITE                CELL                MODEL
ABC                 123                 M12
END


CONNECTION DATA
UNIT               CELL
U123               456
END
```

Actually it prints output as:

```
Hi - END
```

I was expecting it to print output (i.e., `Hi - END`) two times, since there are two `END` keywords in the file.

When I remove `^`, `$` from the regex match (`if ($line =~ /END/);`) it could able to print `Hi - END` two times. But with `^`, `$` it prints only once. Why so?

Comment: `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper $line;` to see what is in the variables. The only reason it would not match is because there is something there hidden, like a blank space that you don't see.

Comment: There are two matches - https://ideone.com/xFbrHY

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I get the output twice.

Comment: Thanks all. this was not working in MobaXterm in windows. I could able to run the script fine in Linux machine.

Comment: You can try `/^\s*END\s*$/` and if that works then your problem is an unseen whitespace.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus You're right. There is a space after first `END`. Because `/^END/` works fine.

Comment: @TLP thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some hidden text before or after one of end `END`. Trailing whitespace before the line feed, perhaps? More specifically, maybe a carriage return?

To see what you have, you could use the following:

```perl
use Data::Dumper;

local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print(Dumper($line));
```

If it is trailing whitespace, using `s/\s+\z//` instead of `chomp` will clear it up.

Comment: The issue I am facing when I run the script in MobaXterm in Windows machine.

Comment: What program is the terminal running? A unix emulation environment? Really sounds likely. ("MobaXterm provides all the important remote [...] Unix commands") That makes the guess of a CR even very on-the-nose.. So, what output did you get?

Comment: I got `$VAR1 = "END\r\n";` in first `END`.

Comment: So yeah, you have an unaccounted CR in there. If you're going to read a Windows file on a unix machine, you'll need to convert it (e.g. using `dos2unix`) or compensate.

Comment: thanks for the debugging info.